# ANN with 403 outputs to predict CAD MESH

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to develop a neural network capable of predicting the meshing of a 2D CAD from 4 input parameters, these parameters are the CAD dimensions.

I am treating this problem as a regression one, using MSE, as a loss function, and adamax as optimizar, but the result are around 350 for the loss. i have tried fitting my data with StandardScalar(), and normalizers, but the results are too bad.

I have had results with accuracy = 1, but the results are not satisfactory at all.
I don't know how the neural network is measuring this accuracy in the evaluate() function.
i would like to mesure the error with an euclidean function, because my results are coordinates.
How can i implement this function to my neural network?

the ANN has 406 outputs, a half for x coordinates, and a half for Y coordinates. Is it possible to make a neural network that has 203 outputs with two values ​​at each node (XY)?
or what other solution technique do you recommend.
I annex results of how I have developed the ANN.

inr shape is :  (144,4).

orf shape is :  (144,406)

```
inr=inRef.to_numpy()
orf=outref.to_numpy()
print(inr.shape,orf.shape)

red1= Sequential()
red1.add(Dense(500,activation='linear',input_shape=(4,),kernel_initializer='normal'))
red1.add(Dense(500,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='normal'))
red1.add(Dense(406,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='normal'))
kera.utils.plot_model(red1, 'pcel.png', show_shapes=True)

red1.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer='Adamax')
     
rp1,rp2,rx1,rx2= train_test_split(inr,orf, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 0)

red1.fit(rp1,rx1,validation_split=0.45, validation_freq=2,epochs =100,verbose=0) 
prt,acu=red1x.evaluate(rp2,rx2)
```

i really need help on this, thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: several layers with linear activation is still just a linear combination of input. effectively you are using only one layer right now

Comment: second problem: you can't train a sophisticated model with 500+ params from only few hundred samples. Maybe you can have 10 parameters per output with this amount of training data

Comment: on top of this, spending almost half of the data on validation is a bit too much

Comment: As mentioned in comments use non-linear activation functions for your hidden layers.

Comment: @Marat, thanks for your answer. 
when you say i would better have 10 parameters per output, i will have almost 40 layers output? or a ANN per 10 parameters output? is it efficent?,
and about the activation layers, which could you  recomend me for this type of problems?.
thanks

Comment: @davidVas1126 you only have four inputs. considering you only have 144 samples (more like ~100 in the training set), you can realistically infer at most 10 coefficients from this data (less is better), i.e. ~4000 coefficients max. Just in the first layer you already have 4x500=2000 parameters, then 500x500=25K in the second, etc. I think you would be better of abandoning neural networks altogether and using a regression

Comment: @marat, thanks i understand what you mean, but how can i do a regression with the three variables, (the 4 inputs,203 nodes for X corrdinates and 203 nodes for Ycoordinates).
continuing with an ANN. do you think is posible implement a conv2dTranspose layer ??.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bad results** - For this you have try hyperparameter tuning as well as feature engineering to get the good results. Along with that try different model architectures to minimize your loss. This part is all about experimenting. No one can give right ans for this.

**Accuracy** - Since you are using regression to solve your problem accuracy is not the choice of metric to go for. You can use Root mean squared metric for regression problems. Accuracy is a metric suitable for classification tasks not regression tasks.

**Constructing 203 outputs with two values** -  You can do this by using funtional API in tensorflow. Using functional api you can multiple inputs as well as multiple outputs. In this example I will show you both the cases. You can adapt the example below for creating your model.
Code:

```
def create_model():
    input1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,), name = 'I1')
    input2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(6,), name = 'I2')
    
    hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation='relu')(input1)
    hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 4, activation='relu')(input2)
    merge = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([hidden1, hidden2])
    hidden3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3, activation='relu')(merge)
    output1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='linear', name ='O1')(hidden3)
    output2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 2, activation='linear', name = 'O2')(hidden3)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = [input1,input2], outputs = [output1,output2])
    
    model.compile(optimizer='Adamax',
                  loss='mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])
    return model


model = create_model3()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, 'my_first_model.png', show_shapes=True)
```

Image:

[image: Model Image]

For training:

```
history = model.fit(
    x = {'I1':x1, 'I2':x2}, 
    y = {'O1':y1, 'O2': y2},
    batch_size = 32,
    epochs = 10,
    verbose = 1,
    callbacks = None
#     validation_data = [(val_data,new_val_data),(val_labels, new_val_labels)]
)
```

Comment: Can you plz accept and upvote if the solution worked.

Comment: thanks a lot four your help.
i am trying to make euclidean distance as a loss function, because i am treating coordinates. Do you think is good to make this function? or is better just to use MSE. or instead using it as a loss function, can i use it in metrics?.
if a use 2 metrics in my model, how these can affect the behavior of it?

Comment: You can use multiple metrics. It doesn't have any effect on training apart from some increase in training time as these metrics need to be calculated. You can write your own custom metric. Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#custom_metrics). Apart from this, you can choose from already available metrics in TensorFlow. Check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics)